# react native android build error (on mac) - unexpected end of file (gradlew)

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am using a mac mini M1 to build a react native app for Android.
The app builds fine on my windows computer, but when trying to build on my mac mini I get the error

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
./gradlew: line 188: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Im wondering if this has anything to do with fact that I created the app originally on Windows.....and this is the first time Im trying to build on Mac?
I checked gradlew file in VSCode and its showing as LF (not CRLF) which as I understand it is correct when building for Mac

Comment: What's on this line? `./gradlew: line 188: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: line 188 is an empty line (the end of the file)

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by a mismatch in the line endings of your files. On Windows, line endings are typically represented by carriage return + line feed (CRLF), while on Unix-based systems they are just represented by line feed (LF).

To fix this, you can either convert all of your files to use LF endings (if you are using a Unix-based system) or CRLF endings (if you are using Windows), or you can set the `lineSeparator` property in your `gradle.properties` file to match the Line Separator of your operating system. More information on this can be found in the Gradle documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Can you please provide more direction on how one would "set the lineSeparator property in your gradle.properties file"......I see no property in my gradle.properties file named lineSeparator